# How to avoid recompiling the same Eclipse plugin that is a dependency of several other plugins

Tags: ant, eclipse-rcp

I have several Eclipse projects, each of them is an RCP plugin. All of them has a dependency on another common project which is itself an RCP plugin.

I have been building each project in Ant like this:

```
<java jar="${eclipse.equinox.launcher.plugin}" fork="true" failonerror="true">
    <arg value="-application"/>
    <arg value="org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner"/>
    <arg value="-buildfile"/>
    <arg value="${eclipse.pde.build.plugin}/scripts/productBuild/productBuild.xml"/>
    <arg value="-Dbuilder=${build.directory.projectroot}"/>
</java>
```

However, with this the common project is rebuilt for each dependent project, which is quite slow and unnecessary. Is there a way to only build/compile the common project once and use the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by copying the already-built plugins into the `dropins` folder of the Eclipse Target. PDE detects these plugins upon building other products and doesn't rebuild them.